# NumberFormatter function not working correctly with German Locale

Tags: android, locale, numberformatter

I needed to add the appropriate engineering notations (K, M, B, T) as per Locale for English and European lanuages. I figured that  using [NumberFormatter](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/icu/number/NumberFormatter) is suggested for Android API 30+.

I have implemented this function to do the conversion which works smooth for English and other EU languages except German which is very strange. I have tested against Spanish, French and Italian.

I need help in figuring out what could be the reason it is not working for German as it is highly important language for my case to support.

```
/**
 * Converts Number to appropriate rounded off format with max 1 decimal place
 * e.g. 1345 --> 1.3K, 15555900 --> 15.6M
*/
private fun formatCount(number: Long) = NumberFormatter.with()
    .notation(Notation.compactShort())
    .decimal(NumberFormatter.DecimalSeparatorDisplay.ALWAYS)
    .precision(Precision.fixedFraction(1))
    .locale(Resources.getSystem().configuration.locales.get(0))
    .format(number)
    .toString()
```

Comment: Is your phone/emulator is in German language as well when testing? Shouldn’t be necessary but can be worth checking if the api is picking up that setting as well auotmagically.

Comment: I have tested on Tablet and Emulator and of course I need to change the language setting to enable the right "Locale" starts applying. I can also confirm that it picks the right locale setting for German. It's a very strange behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe that is specific to the Language itself. For example, in German, I think, there is no representation of a thousand with a character like **K**. or even for ten thousand.
Similarly in Japan, there is no representation for a thousand but there is for 10 thousand **万**. Below are some examples

```
Locale.GERMANY
----------------
15 -> 15,0
135 -> 135,0
1345 -> 1345,0
13455 -> 13.455,0
134555 -> 134.555,0
1345555 -> 1,3 Mio.
15555900 -> 15,6 Mio.
155559000 -> 155,6 Mio.
1555590000 -> 1,6 Mrd.

Locale.JAPAN
-------------
15 -> 15.0
135 -> 135.0
1345 -> 1345.0
13455 -> 1.3万
134555 -> 13.5万
1345555 -> 134.6万
15555900 -> 1555.6万
155559000 -> 1.6億
1555590000 -> 15.6億

Locale.FRANCE
---------------
15 -> 15,0
135 -> 135,0
1345 -> 1,3 k
13455 -> 13,5 k
134555 -> 134,6 k
1345555 -> 1,3 M
15555900 -> 15,6 M
155559000 -> 155,6 M
1555590000 -> 1,6 Md
```

If you notice even though there are no characters added as a suffix to the number value but there is always a single-digit decimal. Which is the intention of your code. Only in Germany, the point(.) is reversed with a comma (,).

Comment: Yes, you made a valid point. It was just lack of enough testing on my end. it does show "Mio" with German locale and there is no "K" because German numbering system doesn't have one.